# Qt with QOpenGLWidget Core Profile: Lots of shader compiling errors

Tags: c++, macos, qt, opengl

I use a `QOpenGLWidget`on my Qt 5.7 app, under MacOS 10.12, with an Intel GPU.

I try to request core profiles using

```
QSurfaceFormat format;
format.setDepthBufferSize(24);
format.setStencilBufferSize(8);
format.setVersion(3, 2);
format.setProfile(QSurfaceFormat::CoreProfile);
QSurfaceFormat::setDefaultFormat(format);
```

as suggested in http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglwidget.html

Now, when I do this, I get lots of shader/compilation errors, such as

```
QOpenGLShader::compile(Fragment): ERROR: 0:1: '' :  #version required and missing.

*** Problematic Fragment shader source code ***
#define lowp
#define mediump
#define highp
#line 1

lowp vec4 srcPixel(); 
void main() 
{ 
    gl_FragColor = srcPixel(); 
}

lowp vec4 srcPixel() 
{ 
    return vec4(0.98, 0.06, 0.75, 1.0); 
}
```

Not that I did not write nor compiled any of these shaders: they are all from Qt. I've made some research already and found out that this has to do with Intel GPU drivers/OpenGL implementation from Intel, which does not allow the first line not to be `#version`.

But is this expected from Qt?? Is there any way I could solve this?

Comment: Have you tried simply adding the required `#version` string at the top of the shader?

Comment: @G.M. these are not my shaders. These are some generic shaders Qt tries to compile for himself.