# QOpenGlShader: #Version required and missing?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, fragment-shader

#### The Problem

I'm encountering a compilation error for my fragment shader on the following platform.

- **Operating System**: `macOS 10.11.6`
- **Open GL**: `4.1 INTEL-10.14.74`

My specific error output is:

```
QOpenGLShader::compile(Fragment): ERROR: 0:1: '' :  #version required and missing.
```

This is followed up by:

```
ERROR: 0:2: ':' : syntax error: syntax error

*** Problematic Fragment shader source code ***
#define lowp
#define mediump
#define highp
#line 1
:/shaders/fragshader.glsl
```

I'll first show my current fragment shader code, then explain what I've tried to do in order to fix this.

---

#### Fragment Shader

```
#version 330 core

// Import: The vertex color to be rendered.
in vec3 vertexColor;

// Export: Fragment shader color (RGBA).
out vec4 fColor;

void main () {
    // Compute the color as a function of the transformed normal vector.
    fColor = vec4(normalize(vertexColor) * 0.5 + 0.5, 1.0);
}
```

---

#### Attempted Solutions

I've found the following SO posts and attempted the following solutions:

**1**: I tried [fangda's solution for similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33482388/2100609) on this question [Qt5 OpenGL GLSL version error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17390970/qt5-opengl-glsl-version-error).

```
QSurfaceFormat glFormat;
glFormat.setVersion(3, 3);
glFormat.setProfile(QSurfaceFormat::CoreProfile);
QSurfaceFormat::setDefaultFormat(glFormat);
```

This was added to my `main.cpp`, but did not alter the error whatsoever.

**2**: I found [Rodrigo Hernandez's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28378436/2100609) to this question [Serious rendering issues with OpenGL 4.1 and Qt 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25858868/serious-rendering-issues-with-opengl-4-1-and-qt-5)

> I Added some comments to your bug report and voted it up. It is indeed
>   a Qt bug, as stated here:
>   https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Core_Language_%28GLSL%29#Version the first
>   preprocessor directive should be #version, but Qt adds defines for
>   lowp, mediump and highp on its own breaking this requirement. Nvidia
>   drivers lets you get away with it, but Intel's does not (I do not know
>   about ATI's), so perhaps the developers in charge did not test on
>   different enough hardware configurations.
>
> As it is, there is no easy workaround, you could change the Qt code
>   not to add those defines (which is a distribution nightmare), or not
>   use the QOpenGLShader class, which means house keeping the raw OpenGL
>   objects yourself.

However, I don't know how I would "change the Qt code to not add those defines" if it is a preprocessor task. It also seems quite extreme.

**3**: I have found this perfect question [Qt with QOpenGLWidget Core Profile: Lots of shader compiling errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40580416/qt-with-qopenglwidget-core-profile-lots-of-shader-compiling-errors) which matches my problem exactly...

But nobody has written an answer. So I'm once again unsure how to solve this.

---

Hernandez's link makes it clear that the error is likely being caused because symbolic constants are being inserted before my `#version` line, which is not allowed:

> The #version directive must appear before anything else in a shader, save for whitespace and comments. If a #version directive does not appear at the top, then it assumes 1.10, which is almost certainly not what you want.

Unfortunately, I simply do not know how I can force my installation of OpenGL with Qt to not insert those symbols constants.

Comment: Have you tried "*not use the QOpenGLShader class*"?

Comment: if this is a bug in Qt5 I just have to believe there is an update coming soon. so the third option is to just sit and wait for that update (at the very least it is a "cheap" solution). (then again, my experience with Qt OpenGL is it being broken some way or the other most of the time... I ultimately abandoned Qt)

Comment: any update on this? seems to still be broken sigh

Comment: I would like to add that I am also seeing this error, and am frustrated to say that I will likely have to skip Qt's abstraction and write my own.